# Why do HTML/SVG Coordinate 0,0 starts at top left corner?

Tags: javascript, html, svg

Just wondering whats the reasoning behind saying 0,0 as top left corner in browser by both HTML/SVG? Are there any advantage to this?

It goes against conventional wisdom (classic geometry) that the Y values become greater in value the lower they are on the screen.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not a practical, answerable problem but a “why” question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Because that's how CSS which predates SVG works.](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#InitialCoordinateSystem)

*In most cases, such as stand-alone SVG documents or SVG document fragments embedded (by reference or inline) within XML parent documents where the parent's layout is determined by CSS [CSS2] or XSL [XSL], the initial viewport coordinate system (and therefore the initial user coordinate system) has its origin at the top/left of the viewport, with the positive x-axis pointing towards the right, the positive y-axis pointing down,*

Comment: HTML 2.0 (from 1995) predates both CSS and SVG and has server-side image maps (`<img ... ismap>`), with the upper left corner of an image defined as (0, 0).

Comment: Well the concept predates CSS also.  It goes all the way back to when computers first started displaying graphics.  I suppose it has something to do with aligning graphical coordinates with text coordinates, which naturally start at the top left.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau "I suppose it has something to do with aligning graphical coordinates with text coordinates, which naturally start at the top left." — That seems to be the correct explanation. I recently started javascript, and the location of the origin plus the direction of the y-axis bothered me. Now that I know that there was a good reason behind it, it seems more manageable. :)

Answer (score 2):

This is the origin of a typical television, and most likely was translated to computer monitors when they were invented. The first pixel drawn to the screen is at top left location...it cascades across to the right, and down from there.

The [windows coordinate system](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/gdi/window-coordinate-system) places the 0,0 point at the top left of their rectangles.